# Angular deep linking - Apache Tomcat

Tags: angular, apache, tomcat, deep-linking

I'm building an Angular app. It is hosted with base a href as `/hris`. So my base url to access the app will be `domain.com/hris`. Further, I have 3 different apps of which one is called `term`. So when I click on the `term` link it goes to domain.com/hris/term.

When the user directly tries to access the link `domain.com/hris/term`, it returns 404 with a message: `HTTP Status 404 - /hris/term`.

I don't want 404 to occur. How to get this done?

What I have done so far:

I tried to create a `.htaccess` file in the folder, where `index.html` resides.(I built the Angular app using `ng build --base-href=/hris/`). I deployed the `dist` folder to the server in a directory called `hris`.

In the `.htaccess` file I used the following variants, to no avail.

## 1

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteBase /hris/
          RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteRule . index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```

## 2

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```

## 3

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
   </IfModule>
```

I am using Angular 5. Please let me know if my approach is right, or what I have to do to get this going.

Version: Apache Tomcat 7- Version 7.0.64

Answer (score 9, accepted):

".htaccess" files do not work on Tomcat. Put the rewriting config into a file `WEB-INF/rewrite.conf`, maybe like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```

Next you need to add a file called `META-INF/context.xml` which enables the rewriting, i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context reloadable="true" tldValidation="false" xmlValidation="false">

  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

</Context>
```

Also remove the [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) from your Angular app.

**Update**

***Why rewriting***

- Since Angular apps are [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)s the only real page that gets addressed at all is `index.html`.
- Therefore any link like an `href` would leave that page and quit the app.
- Angular uses its [Router](https://angular.io/guide/router) to redirect to virtual paths inside the app, without leaving `index.html`.
- A web server would guess these paths are real files and since they do not exist, respond with an 404 HTTP status (in case of Tomcat its the [DefaultServlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/default-servlet.html) serving static content).
- To get around this problem [url rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) can be used.

***How to enable rewriting***

- First you need to enable the [RewriteValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html), which is a network filter and is disabled by default. To do so, you can add a `context.xml` to your Angular build file, like in the example above (portable version), or add it to the `server.xml` (server-side version). See code snippets above.
- After that add a `rewrite.conf` file to setup the [rewriting conditions](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html#Directives). See code snippets above.
- In the example above the first line tells Tomcat to look for "files which are not real/existing files" `!-f`, in the current servlet path. The servlet path part is neccessary, if your app is not deployed as `ROOT` (i.e. [www.xyz.com/**myApp**](http://www.xyz.com/**myApp**)) and will be set accordingly.
- The second line mapps every "virtual path" from the Angular router to index.html.

**Update 2**

- Enabling the [ServiceWorker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro#prerequisites) also resolves the problem.

Comment: Could you please provide some links that go in more details on your answer? I thought one could configure an .htaccess for tomcat as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should create WEB-INF/rewrite.conf and then META-INF/context.xml inside the src folder of my Angular project?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure they both end up in the `dist` folder after build. So you need to add them to `angular.json` in the `assets`section. Run `ng build` after all and check the `dist` folder.

Comment: I tried this a couple of times but somehow I can't get it to work. After running `ng build` the `META-INF` and `WEB-INF` folders are indeed in the `dist` folder. If I do these changes in the server files on the other hand (`server.xml` or creating a `rewrite.conf` file) then it works.

Answer (score 3):

For fixing the deep link issue when deploying angular application (with PathLocationStrategy routing) on apache tomcat server (8, 9) -

1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml
2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config

server.xml -

```
...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

...
      </Host>
...
```

rewrite.config - (note - /hello/ is the context path of the angular app on tomcat)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/hello/(.*) /hello/index.html
```

I have documented this in my article - [Fixing deep linking issue – Deploying angular application on Tomcat server](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/)

Comment: I have tried this, but I'm encountering a problem: each of the three javascript files (runtime.###.js, main.###.js, and polyfills###.js) are ALSO being replaced by the contents of `index.html`.  So the page fails to load.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this question while attempting solve a similar issue. stefan's answer worked for me with a slight modification to the file name. Per https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html, the rewrite configuration file should be named rewrite.config (*not rewrite.conf*).

I do not have enough rep to comment on his answer so I will reiterate here for completeness:

> Put the rewriting config into a file WEB-INF/rewrite.config, maybe like this:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} !-f
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html [L]
> ```
>
> Next you need to add a file called META-INF/context.xml which enables the rewriting, i.e.:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Context reloadable="true" tldValidation="false" xmlValidation="false">
>   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
> </Context>
> ```
>
> Also remove the HashLocationStrategy from your Angular app.