# Angular App deployed on tomcat as war

Tags: angular, tomcat, war

I'd like to deploy a *single page application (SPA)* written in Angular with a bunch of static files, including *.css, *.js, /assets/* within a war file on tomcat.

The problem is, every path given by the user which doesn't match one of the existing files should deliver index.html.

I started with this web.xml configuration:

```
[...]
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.html</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  [...]
```

Unfortunately this *index* also matches existing, static files.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046750/angular-deep-linking-apache-tomcat/50057754#50057754

Answer (score 3):

Every path which doesn't match any file delivers a 404 error code

Working web.xml:

```
[...]
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
[...]
```

On every not found page it will redirect to index.html